# Spawning a new instance of the same view, using a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently trying to spawn a new instance of the same view - using the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    InventoryController *inventoryController = [[InventoryController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InventoryView" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    [navigationController pushViewController:inventoryController animated:YES];

    [inventoryController release];
    [navigationController release];
}
```

Problem is that it's not working...

I don't get any errors or anything - it just doesn't do anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: There appears to be nothing retaining the navigationContoller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PengOne has it right... you're creating a navigation controller and then releasing it, and there's nothing to prevent it from being deallocated. Additionally, you haven't added the nav controller's view to the window, and you haven't set the nav controller as the window's root view controller, so there's no way for the views controlled by controllers in this particular navigation stack to ever be seen.

Try this: Create a navigation-based project in Xcode. You don't need to add any code -- just create the project so that you can look at the code that's provided. You'll see that the app delegate has a retain property for storing the nav controller, and the nav controller is set as the window's root view controller.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, but in my particular case, I don't want it for the full project, just one of the views in a UITabBarController...

Comment: That's fine, it doesn't have to be the app delegate that retains the nav controller, but *somebody* has to hang onto it or it'll be deallocated. You can, for example, [add it to a tab bar controller's array of controllers](http://tinyurl.com/3mb7zdn), in which case your nav controller is retained by the array, which in turn is retained by the tab bar controller.

Answer (score 1):

If your current controller is already a part of UINavigationController hierarchy then you must not create a new navigation controller - use the existing one instead (note that every UIViewController has a reference to its parent UINavigationViewController if it exists):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    InventoryController *inventoryController = [[InventoryController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InventoryView" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:inventoryController animated:YES];

    [inventoryController release];
}
```

Comment: I don't have an existing one :/ - I thought that I could create one on the fly for what I needed to do, but I guess i need to retain it somehow..